# How to make child tmux pane inherit environment variables from parent?

Tags: vim, tmux, iterm2

I am using tmux version 1.8. How do I make sure that when I create a new window/pane, the newly created window inherits the environment variables that were set in the parent pane? Is this possible to do? I found this solution which was posted on stack over flow but this did not work for me.

```
set-option -ga update-environment ' YOUR_VAR'
```

Comment: I figured out a way. Basically you can achieve this by setting the environment variable before you start the tmux session. The new session and all the windows and panes will inherit the environment variables which were set before creating the session. However this will not work if the environment variables are overridden in any of the .*rc files that may be invoked.